# WPA_GUI can't load wpa_supplicant

Tags: raspbian, wireless, gui, wpa

I am new to the raspberry pi and can't quite seem to figure this one out.

The wpa_gui is blank in the adapter and network field and reporting the error "Could not get status from wpa_supplicant"

Content of /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
#Needed for wpa_gui to work
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

#Needed for wpa_gui to alter the configuration file
update_config=1

network={
ssid=spl-public
psk=""

#Protocal type can be: RSN(for WP2) and WPA(for WPA1)
proto=WPA

#Key managment type can be: WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP (Pre-Shared or Enterprise)
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

#Pairwise can be CMMP or TKIP(for WPA2 or WPA1)
pairwise=TKIP

#Authorization option should be OPEN for both WPA1/WPA2 (in less commonly used are SHARED and LEAP)
auth-alg=OPEN
}
```

Content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet lopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

The wpa_supplicant.conf file references to a directory /var/run/wpa_supplicant, this does not exist on my system. What should be here?

```
sudo ifup --force wlan0
```

Returns:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start run-parts: 
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1 

Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory 
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start run-parts:
/etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure that wlan0 is up?  Try running `sudo ifup --force wlan0`  I had to do that once when wpa_supplicant wasn't running on my system.

Comment: Hum. If I run that it says "Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory"

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` show?

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:d0:2a:12  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: I didn't give enough info on the ifup force because I was currently on my phone only. Here is the full error:


wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1

Comment: Have you checked if anything is logged in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: Is your pre-shared key really `""`?  Or did you just update the key for the posting?  FYI, there is a minimum length for the pre-shared key.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn will remove that and try that thanks. I will let your know.  I will also check the logs in the directory. Get back to you shortly.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn thanks for the psk lengh minimum. I was initially at the public library so there was no key I left it blank. Dec 22 08:34:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[5729]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Dec 22 08:34:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[5729]: Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
Dec 22 08:34:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[5729]: rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device

After checking the logs (Thanks for pointing those out super new to raspberry pi). the .conf file wasn't loading. Now that it is loading looks like it's a driver issue.

Comment: A possibly irrelevant remark: There's a typo "lopback" (instead of "loopback") in your interfaces file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem that was preventing the configuration file from loading was this key:

auth-alg=OPEN --> auth_alg=OPEN

It says it is not valid. I got it from a tutorial might be outdated.

Thanks to everyone in the comments who helped out.

Comment: so you changed `auth-alg` to `auth_alg` ?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your question.

Answer (score 1):

I got same messages and solved. It caused by wrong text description.

In wpa_supplicant.conf file:

1.
 auth-algalg=OPEN -> auth_alg=OPEN

"_"UNDERBAR should be right. ( It should work without it )

2.
  ssid=spl-public -> ssid="spl-public"

"" DOUBLE-QUOTE would be required for SSID text.

In my case, the following line was wrong,

ssid ="" -> ssid=""

because it contains one SPACE after the word "ssid"

Comment: remove space - It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue due to a botched interface file (should have backed it up first!)

Heres a default file for rasberry pi's `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

You can test your configuration by running `/sudo/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

If you are finding that your wifi dongle does not reconnect to your wifi network after your Raspberry Pi reboots add: `auto wlan0`  to the bottom of your config and restart the service or reboot (this is what fixed it for me).

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the problem by power supply too low.

I using a usb-hub as power.

Direct connect to laptop usb port, wpa_cli will work.

Please check that too.

Answer (score -1):

I am on Raspi 2 and I have been having the same problem for the last few days, just solved this a few minutes ago. It seems that wpa_supplicant.conf has a very strict format. In my case, the problem just the spaces between 'network' and '=' and '{'. By deleting the spaces it just work (of course after restarting it by 'sudo ifdown wlan0' and 'sudo ifup wlan0'.

Hope this helps.

originally:

```
network = {
...
...
...
}
```

remove space between 'network' and '=' and '{'

```
network={
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: But from the example given by @Cubicle.Jokey, this isn't likely the problem in his case, right?

Comment: Yeah as you can see in my own answer, the configuration value was wrong, their documentation had the value wrong.

They documented it with auth-alg but it should have been auth_alg.

Although I am very curious why people keep answering this questions years later, when it has a accepted answer.