# Setting up wifi with wpa_supplicant error

Tags: hardware, wireless, wifi, driver

I purchased a TP-LINK TL-WN725N usb adaptor to connect to wifi, as I don't have an ethernet cable long enough to reach my router (on a different floor).

I've installed the drivers for my kernel version, and iwconfig shows wlan0 showing up. Trying to restart the network service (as per the tutorial I was following) however results an error along the lines of:

```
/etc/sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpa_supplicant exited with return code 1
failed to connect to wpa_supplicant --wpa_ctrl_open: no such file or directory
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks something like (aside from the default ethernet stuff):

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "******"
wpa-psk "******"
```

In my search for a solution I've frequently come across ideas such as 'install wicd', but alas until I get the wireless working I can't download anything to the device. Is it feasible to configure wifi through wpa_supplicant on rasbian with this particular adaptor, and if so how should I be setting up wpa_supplicant? I've seen a few different variations and I've yet to try a combination that has not given me this error.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to take the pi to your router, and use the ethernet cable to get the packages you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPA\_GUI can't load wpa\_supplicant](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12424/wpa-gui-cant-load-wpa-supplicant)

Comment: @kolin that would involve also getting an hdmi monitor there, power cables, etc. I'll see if I can connect ethernet from my PC to the pi and share my internet connection that way.

Comment: 50m of ethernet costs about $10, and if your wifi reaches there, the 50m cable would too.

Comment: I think "get a very long ethernet cable" is not really a solution to a wireless adapter configuration issue.

Comment: @LucasPenney you wouldn't need a hdmi monitor, just a cat5 cable. once you've plugged it it, you can ssh to it, and get your packages that way, it's not necessary to have a hdmi monitor. to connect it to your PC you may need a crossover cable.